# Read a line specifying the position

Tags: c#

I have a text file and if suppose the text file have 94 characters in each line,i want to read first 12 characters one time and next 5 characters for a time and so on.How can i read like that in c#
Actually i tried like this

```
        StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(filePath);
        string line;
        bool endOfFile = false;
        string[] strProcessedTokens = new string[1000];
        int i = 0;

        while (!reader.EndOfStream & !endOfFile)
        {

           line = reader.ReadLine()
        .Select(m => new
        {
            firstGroup = m.Substring(0, 12),
            secondGroup = m.Substring(12, 5),
            lastGroup = m.Substring(89, 5)
       });

            requestProcessor.ProcessRequest(line);
            strProcessedTokens[i++] = line;
        }
```

Comment: where is the code you tried?

Comment: i have an idea how to read the line from a text file,but no idea on this how to read from a specific position

Comment: just use Substring(<start>, <end>) ?

Comment: @ Raphaël Althaus  --if u dont mind can u give me an example

Comment: By what logic do what to you arrive at this number of characters 12,5,..etc

Comment: @ramboo i just gave those as sample.i have some uneven order of requirement for positions of the line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the numbers used in the Substring(s), but something like that

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(<PathOfYourFile>)
            .Select(m => new {
               firstGroup = m.Substring(0, 12),
               secondGroup = m.Substring(12, 5),
               //etc.
               lastGroup = m.Substring(89,5)
            });
```

File.ReadAllLines will be ok for a "reasonable" file size.

**EDIT**
With your code, you could do

```
while (!reader.EndOfStream & !endOfFile)
        {

           line = reader.ReadLine();
           var firstGroup = line.Substring(0,12);
           var secondGroup = line.Substring(12, 5);
           var lastGroup = line.Substring(89,5);


            requestProcessor.ProcessRequest(line);
            strProcessedTokens[i++] = line;
        }
```

Comment: an error----char(m) doesnot contain a definiton for substring

Comment: @sindhujampani Did you really used the given code ?

Comment: yes..how can i say the error by not using the code?

Comment: @sindhujampani Cause I can use this code without errors. Well show the actual code in your question please. There must be something weird somewhere.

Comment: `m` isn't a char though, its a string, so the code posted should work.  Note this replaces the original `while (!reader...` block, not just the `var line` piece.

Comment: @sindhujampani so don't tell you use the given code ! File.ReadAllLines will return an `IEnumerable<string>`, while `reader.ReadLine` will return a string. So use File.ReadAllLine, or don't use a `.Select`